# Rails 4 & Angular 2 update an array of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

So I have an array of models in Angular i.e.:

```
[
   {id: "asdasdasd3232", value: 200},
   {id: "asdasdasd3232", value: 200},
   ...
   {id: "asdasdasd3232", value: 200}
]
```

I'm sending this to rails for updating using Mongoid. I'm getting undefined `id' from ActionController::Parameters. What's the correct way of doing this?

I'm a beginner in Rails so assuming my Angular is correct, how do I receive and update all of them in Rails.

Hope anyone can help. Thanks!

EDIT:
So here's my controller action:

```
def update_all
   rows = params[:rows]
   rows.each do |r|
      m = Model.find(r.id)
      m.update(r)
   end
end
```

And my route:

```
resources :models do
   collection do
      post :update_all
   end
end
```

Comment: Show the controller action you send data to.

Comment: i'd prefer if you can give your own since mine isn't really correct. What I want is just to update those values in any way that Rails allows it.

Comment: And also show your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Already shown my routes

Comment: Change `r.id` to `r[:id]`

Comment: Did that already and still the same error, also did r['id'].

Comment: Show the whole error message